# Chrome extension for tabs

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I was creating a simple chrome extension where every time we click on a link it should open on a new tab. How can I get that link and pass it to the chrome.tabs.create function? Like for example if I search something on Google then the links which appear on the page, I should be able to get those links on a new tab by clicking on them.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a content script that does this:

```js
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll("a"),
  anchorsLen = anchors.length;

for (var i = 0; i < anchorsLen; i++) {
  var a = anchors[i];
  a.target = "_blank";
}
```

Comment: But if i click on a link will it open on a new tab?..or will I have to add the onclick function to this code snippet?

Comment: @AmitNaik it will open in a new tab because of the `target="_blank"` that this js snippet adds to all anchors

Comment: I need to somehow dynamically get the URL by clicking on it. Is there a way to do this? I don't want to hardcode any specific URL in my html page.

Comment: @AmitNaik You don't need to get the url for your purpose, you just need to add the target attribute. WHich is what my code snippet does. Give it a try and you will see...